# How can I streamline uniform declarations of lazy-loaded routes?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am working on a large Angular/strict TypeScript application with hundreds of lazily loaded modules.

In many places, we are building up routing tables like this:

```js
[{
  path: 'module1-feature1',
  loadChildren: () => import('modules/module1/feature1').then(m => m.Module1Feature1Module)
}, {
  path: 'module1-feature2',
  loadChildren: () => import('modules/module1/feature2').then(m => m.Module1Feature2Module)
}, {
  path: 'module2-feature1',
  loadChildren: () => import('modules/module2/feature1').then(m => m.Module2Feature1Module)
}]
```

Now, looking at just one of these blocks:

```js
{
  path: 'module1-feature1',
  loadChildren: () => import('modules/module1/feature1').then(m => m.Module1Feature1Module)
}
```

It becomes evident that there's an awful lot of redundancy in here - I count three mentions of "module1" and three mentions of "feature1". Considering the application scale of hundreds of such modules, that means plenty of extra work in the case of renames, plenty of opportunities for our developers to make mistakes, etc.

**Is there any way to streamline this in such a way that I define a `ModuleRoute` class that would shorten my routing table?** I am hoping for something like this:

```js
[
  new ModuleRoute('module1', 'feature1'),
  new ModuleRoute('module1', 'feature2'),
  new ModuleRoute('module2', 'feature1')
]
```

Doing this for the path (or for an eagerly loaded module, for that matter) seems straightforward. My two problems here are:

- I have tried dynamically building the string passed to the `import` keyword (I know it's not an ordinary function, but some kind of TypeScript magic), but that seemed to mess up at least my IDE's capability of resolving the route; probably also the routing in the running application.
- Even if I *could* dynamically build that import path, I'm not sure what to return in the `then` part. I might use the `[]` notation to access a member of `m` whose name is a module name following the pattern used here, but even so, I'm not sure what I should cast that to to make TypeScript accept the resulting type.

(I am not sure those are really two separate problems. If they are, the first one certainly is the main focus of this question.)

Comment: I don't have any real help on the first part, but the second part seems pretty straightforward: modules should implement an interface. I know that's sometimes easier said, but it's type safe (which is better than hoping the module follows convention)

Comment: @JasonWarner: Yes, but *which* interface? Or do you mean a custom one? Isn't anything specific required for `loadChildren` to work as a promise'd return value? Maybe not, seeing that [`LoadChildrenCallback`](https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildrenCallback) may return `Promise<Type<any>>` ... but then, I'm still confused about what types exactly that allows for; apparently not abstract types, but how about types with ctor parameters? Will have to read up on this.

Comment: I would assume a custom interface, but that's actually out of my depth. All of my projects are react - I was reading the Q to gain insight into how Angular works with modularization and features. I have no need for that now - but I like to be ready :)